# Why Cordova geolocation plugin is not working on Ripple Emulator anymore?

Tags: cordova, gps, cordova-plugins, ripple, taco

I have create a Cordova app using the following tools/platforms:

- Visual Studio 2015
- Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova
- Ripple Emulator 0.9.32
- Cordova 5.3.1

I was using the compass and GPS capabilities from Ripple to emulate them. Using Ripple heading slider and loading a GPX file, I could emulate new heading, latitude, longitude values which were detected by my app. Everything was working fine two weeks ago.

The problem started two days ago. Although the compass emulation was working fine, the app could not receive any new coordinates from the GPS. I have tested with older versions of my app with no success and also on 3 different machines.

I have tested the full example from the cordova geolocation plugin (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova/geolocation/geolocation.watchPosition.html) on three different machines with no success. The geolocation and GPX does not work on Ripple Emulator. I have also tested not using Visual Studio but Cordova CLI and running “ripple emulate” through the Command Prompt.

Something has changed. I have not upgraded Visual Studio. Therefore, my guess is that Ripple Emulator 0.9.32 is not compatible with the new version of Google Chrome since it seems that there was  an update from version 47.0.2526.111 to 48.0.2.564.97 a few days ago. I have done some research and it seems that is not very easy to install older versions of Chrome.

Can somebody shed some light on this topic? Are you able to emulate GPS values using Ripple Emulator 0.9.32 on your Cordova app using Google Chrome 48.0.2.564.97?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are clicking the "Success" button when the [Geolocation.getPermission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcZr3.jpg) dialog pops up in Ripple.

You might want to try clearing your Cordova Cache. In VS: Tools->Options, Tools for Apache Cordova, and Clear Cordova Cache.

You could also try clearing the Chrome user directory that Ripple uses, just in case there's a cookie set that's breaking the cordova plugin. You can do so by deleting this folder: %AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\MDA\RPL_UserData

I can also recommend you update your VS Tools for Apache Cordova to the latest version. [Here's](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723751) the link for Update 6.